# Access list of list in JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have created a list of lists that contains content that I want to display through a jsp file. when trying to just display the items through one list, the file works and I see it. But when I split the items in different arraylists and try to iterate over that, nothing shows up. My initialization is,

```
private final List<ArrayList<DisplayableProduct>> listOfThreeProducts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<DisplayableProduct>>();
```

I have verified that there is content inside each list of it through debugging.

my model.listofThreePorducts is a list of lists. so I want to loop through the list of lists and then loop inside each loop and so stuff. Is it correct to pass the var="listoflists" value to the second for loop as such below? would it be items="${listoflists}" to access everything in that list ?

```
    <c:forEach items="${model.listOfThreeProducts}" var="listoflists">
        <div id="hero-featureSwap">
            <c:forEach items="${listoflists}" var="product">
                    <div class="widget-element-brand"
                        title='<awsmp:formatText text="${product.vendorName}" />'>
                        <awsmp:formatText text="${product.vendorName}" maxLength="25" />
                    </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Your current code is right and should work. If it doesn't work, provide the necessary code to replicate the problem.

Comment: you have `model` attribute available in request/session/application/page context, you have `getListOfThreeProducts()` method inside that object ? you have `getVendorName()` inside product class ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi listOfThreeProducts is a variable in the model. Maybe I am reading the var tag wrong, I am using it as a name. There does not exist a listoflists variable in model. It was used a placeholder to be used in the inner for loop. Is this wrong?

Comment: its fine if it is a variable in model, but does it have getter method

Comment: @JigarJoshi It did not, but I just added it. did not know that there had to be a getter method to access it

Comment: there has to be a standard getter to resolve the EL to the object

Comment: @JigarJoshi that was the solution!

Comment: adding as solution feel free to upvote/mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need standard getter in `model` object for property `listOfThreeProducts`

<sub>further detail discussed in question's comment section</sub>